# TypeError: myObservableArray is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an observable array that I want to be able to delete entries from via a button in the HTML using the knockout.js framework. However, when I try to use the observable array `this.comments` in the `deleteComment` function, I get a `TypeError: this.comments is undefined`, even though it is clearly defined and has entries. `this.comments` is even used in the `entryComments` function which works perfectly fine. Am I missing something?

HTML/PHP:

```
 <div class="textblock">
            <h1>User Comments</h1>
            <ul id="usercomment"  data-bind="foreach: comments">
                <li><p><strong data-bind="text: comment"></strong> - <strong data-bind="text: user"></strong></p>
                       <button data-bind="visible: display(), click: $parent.deleteComment.bind($data, $index)" >Delete Comment</button>


                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br />
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])): ?>
<?php if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true): ?>
            <div class="textblock">
                <ul>
                    <li>      
                        <form name="commentform" data-bind="submit: enterComment.bind($data,$data.comment )">
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.comment"/>
                            <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Javascript:

```
var AppViewModel = function (commentList, userList) {
    //Initializing data
    this.displayButton = ko.observable(false);
    this.comments = ko.observableArray();
    this.username;
     $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/sem4/recept/UserInfo.php",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            username = data.username;
        }
    });  
    //Giving the array values
    for(var i = 0;i<=commentList.length -1;i++ ){

        if(username === userList[i]){
             this.comments.push(new Comment(commentList[i],userList[i],true ));
        }
        else{
             this.comments.push(new Comment(commentList[i],userList[i], false));
        }
    };    
    //Function is called but it cannot define this.comments
      this.deleteComment = function(index){

          this.comments.splice(index,1);

      }
    //This function works without any problems
    this.enterComment = function (comment) {
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/sem4/recept/UserInfo.php",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            username = data.username;
        }
    });

        this.comments.push(new Comment(comment, username,true));
      $.post("http://localhost/sem4/recept/AddComment.php", {
    comment: comment,
    username: username
});
    };



    //OBJECTS
     function Comment(comment, user,bool) {
        var self = this;
        self.comment = ko.observable(comment);
        self.user = ko.observable(user);
         self.display = ko.observable(bool);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this scope changes when you use a function. a regular workaround is defining a self variable at the top and using it when you need to access the whole function scope.

```
var AppViewModel = function (commentList, userList) {
    //Initializing data
    var self = this;
    ....

    self.deleteComment = function(index){
       self.comments.splice(index,1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, I've seen people do that but I did not know what it was for. Seems to work now though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is to use an arrow function, as they inherit `this` from their context.

```
...
     this.deleteComment = (index)=>{ // was function(index){

          this.comments.splice(index,1);

      }
...
```